# What can I do when a vendor goes into administration before delivering everything I've paid for?

Tags: loans, school, contracts

My son took out a loan to pay for a a course, the course provider has now gone into administration. My son is still paying for the loan for a course he cant access. My question is - has he any redress, can he pull out of the loan agreement or get his money back . The loan company is one recommended by the course provider

Comment: This maybe off topic here. You would need to add country tag and give more details of the course in question as well as type of loan [personal loan, Govt sanctioned student loan etc]

Comment: as already stated a country would be most helpful but in general as also suggested, there is a government agency akin to Department of Education that usually monitors these situations and a filing with them should provide some recourse.

Answer (score 8):

Unless the loan provider is pretty darned directly attached to the course provider, the loan is an independent transaction. It isn't the bank's fault the other company went into receivership; it isn't reasonable to expect them to cover your loss. Your best bet is to either try to get some of your money back from the course provider (which may take years for partial repayment), or to try to at least pry a copy of the rest of the course out of their hands (costs them relatively little, and you did pay for it).

You may have other rights and redresses under law, but that will depend on where you are,what your contract with the course provider says, and exactly which laws can be applied. That's something I can't advise upon; I Am Not A Lawyer.

Also: Note that a company may continue doing business while in receivership. If the Receiver is doing their job properly, you should get a letter indicating what their plans are in this regard. It's possible you'll get the full program you paid for, which would be the best answer for everyone.